# Attaching files to a channel on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send files to a channel in Teams, but I've found examples of asking a bot for something (for example I write 1 and he send me an image), and the bot's able send images or files like attachments (I don't need adaptive cards or message cards if your idea is `Incoming webhook`).

I need to send with a schedule request attachment files to teams, is that possible? For example, if such is possible to send a set of image attachment every 1 hour.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please offer some despription about your attachment? In my opinion, your request contains two parts -- making the bot send proactive message and setting a time trigger to make the bot send message at a specific time. Another important thing is that the message is in the form of attachment but not text. Sending proactive message to a teams channel and setting time trigger are both realizable.

Comment: Yes, its possible. You can create a scheduler process or implement timer based solutions to send set of image attachment every 1 hours. As @Tiny-wa updated share more info about your attachment...

Comment: My attachments are usually images in PNG format and xlsx files, yes I know that my bot has two parts, the schedule is another challenge, but I'm thinking to use Incoming webhook to send the image and SharePoint to storage it.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still not resolved.

1. Please take a look at [Send and receive files through your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files#using-the-microsoft-graph-apis) doc to see how your bot can send/receive file attachments.
2. For bot to trigger message based on backend trigger, please take a look at [Send
   proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet).

Sample code for both of these scenarios can be found in [Bot Framework sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/#teams-samples) repo.